# Access selectedData from html.Div children

Tags: graph, mouseevent, plotly-dash, plotly-python

In order to avoid displaying empty graph axes when no information is available to plot, I replaced a `dcc.Graph` return object with a `html.Div()` which gets an Output callback of either `[]` or `[dcc.Graph(...)]`.

Now, I'd like to enable other actions on the selectedData (if the Div has a child Graph). Previously I could do this like:

```
@app.callback(Output('something', 'children'), 
              [Input('graph', 'selectedData')])
def do_stuff(selectedData):
    pass
```

Now that I've changed the layout item from a `dcc.Graph(...)` to a `html.Div([dcc.Graph(...)])`, I can't figure out how to access the `selectedData`:

```
@app.callback(Output('something', 'children'), 
              [Input('graph_div', 'children')])
def do_stuff(children):
    if len(children) > 0:
        graph = children[0]
    # wheres the selectedData now?
```

---

Alternatively, it might be easier if there's a way to get the Input `id` directly to nested `dcc.Graph`'s `id`? When I try this I get an error saying no components with this id exist in the app's layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each component, it should be possible to register a callback in Dash,

Here is a simple example which replicates what you are trying to do,

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id="graph-div",
        children=[
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph',
                figure={
                    'data': [
                        {
                            'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                            'y': [4, 1, 3, 5],
                            'text': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                            'customdata': ['c.a', 'c.b', 'c.c', 'c.d'],
                            'name': 'Trace 1',
                            'mode': 'markers',
                            'marker': {'size': 12}
                        },
                        {
                            'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                            'y': [9, 4, 1, 4],
                            'text': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                            'customdata': ['c.w', 'c.x', 'c.y', 'c.z'],
                            'name': 'Trace 2',
                            'mode': 'markers',
                            'marker': {'size': 12}
                        }
                    ],
                    'layout': {
                        'clickmode': 'event+select'
                    }
                }
            ),
        ]
    ),
    html.Div(id="output")
])

@app.callback(Output('output', 'children'), 
              [Input('graph', 'selectedData')])
def do_stuff(selectedData):
    print(selectedData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

If you can post a simple re-creatable code it will be easier to debug.

**Update:**

If you are dynamically trying to load the component you might face the mentioned issue,

https://community.plot.ly/t/dcc-tabs-filling-tabs-with-dynamic-content-how-to-organize-the-callbacks/6377/2

One easy way to solve it would be to set this app configuration,
`app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True`

Here is the working example,

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd


#
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580240/access-selecteddata-from-html-div-children
#


graph_layout = dcc.Graph(
                id='graph',
                figure={
                    'data': [
                        {
                            'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                            'y': [4, 1, 3, 5],
                            'text': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                            'customdata': ['c.a', 'c.b', 'c.c', 'c.d'],
                            'name': 'Trace 1',
                            'mode': 'markers',
                            'marker': {'size': 12}
                        },
                        {
                            'x': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                            'y': [9, 4, 1, 4],
                            'text': ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                            'customdata': ['c.w', 'c.x', 'c.y', 'c.z'],
                            'name': 'Trace 2',
                            'mode': 'markers',
                            'marker': {'size': 12}
                        }
                    ],
                    'layout': {
                        'clickmode': 'event+select'
                    }
                }
            )
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions']=True 

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(id="toggle-graph",
        options=[
            {'label': 'on', 'value': 'on'},
            {'label': 'off', 'value': 'off'},
        ],
        value='on'
    ) , 
    html.Div(id="graph-div",
        children=[

        ]
    ),
    html.Div(id="output")
])


@app.callback(Output('graph-div', 'children'), 
              [Input('toggle-graph', 'value')])
def do_stuff(value):
    if(value == 'on'):
        return graph_layout
    else:
        return []


@app.callback(Output('output', 'children'), 
              [Input('graph', 'selectedData')])
def do_stuff(selectedData):
    print(selectedData)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like the entire graph pane to be shown conditionally though, for example if a checkbox is selected. Is it possible to have a conditional layout object that is used as an input to a callback?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what I needed was a way to toggle the graph display rather than conditionally returning the entire graph object:

```
@app.callback(Output('graph', 'style'), [Input('drop-down', 'value')])
def toggle_container(dropdown_value):
    if something
        return {'display': 'none'}
    else:
        return {'display': 'block'}
```